# Allow user to interact outside of bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a quick and easy way to allow a user to interact with my web page (outside of the modal) while a [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) is showing? I am using version 3 of bootstrap. This would also not cause the modal to close which I am achieving by setting the `backdrop` setting to `false`.

Comment: maybe try the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088897/bootstrap-modal-allow-the-background-interaction-when-modal-open

Comment: @s0rfi949 Thanks. I haven't been able to get that answer to work yet, but am working with it. That is what I am looking for though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer referenced in the comments, I created this css class and added it to the modal div.

```
.modal-allow-interact {
   position: absolute;
   top:50px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: auto;
   width: 800px;  /* this can be however wide you want the modal to be */
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.modal-allow-interact .modal-dialog {
   margin: 0;
}
```