# AngularJS - uibmodal - drag from modal and drop onto parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is it possible to drag an element from a modal window (opened with uibmodal) and drop it on to an area on the parent window?  My issue is that the parent window is always disabled and greyed out and the 'drop area' is disabled.

I have tried playing with the `backdrop` property but none of the options are enabling the background.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is because the modal outer wrapper fills whole screen. Changing `backdrop` only adds a class that sets background for the wrapper

Comment: Any other way around it?

Comment: Perhaps pass various possible locations to modal and select where to move there? Like using a `<select>`??

Comment: For anyone interested - this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388375/enable-background-when-open-bootstrap-modal-popup