# modal popups on backdrop enable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular5

I'm working on modal popups for angular 5.

my requirement totally replicates this SO question [After open model popup user can also work on the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388375/enable-background-when-open-bootstrap-modal-popup?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

but I not like to override all modals styles by mentioning them globally. I need to enable background for particular modals only not for all. Is this possible for me ?